# how do i use isinstance() in django template language

Tags: django

I have been trying this for a while and getting a syntax error that invalid block tag: expected empty

```
 {%if isinstance(object, ClassName)%}
     {%do something here%}
 {%else%}
     {%do something here%}
 {%endif%}
```

can somebody please help me that how do i achieve this

in python console "isinstance(obj,Class)" works perfectly fine and returns true to me.

thanks

Comment: read [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/#if), you can't use arbitrary expressions (i.e. a function call like `isinstance(obj,Class)`) in django template language. you would need to build your own `isinstance` template tag

Comment: `if ==` or `ifequal` see django docshttps://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#ifequal